# Opera background-color issue

Tags: javascript, css, background, opera, footer

This problem is hard to describe.
I do have the following CSS part for the background on a website. It shows an image on the top, right corner and a gradient colored background.

```
body{
    color: #000;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    background: rgb(84,84,84);
    background-color: #545454;
    background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
    background: url(../img/bg.png), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(84,84,84,1) 0%, rgba(117,117,117,1) 34%, rgba(191,191,191,1) 64%, rgba(178,178,178,1) 100%);
    background: url(../img/bg.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(84,84,84,1)), color-stop(34%,rgba(117,117,117,1)), color-stop(64%,rgba(191,191,191,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(178,178,178,1)));
    background: url(../img/bg.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(84,84,84,1) 0%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 34%,rgba(191,191,191,1) 64%,rgba(178,178,178,1) 100%);
    background: url(../img/bg.png), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(84,84,84,1) 0%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 34%,rgba(191,191,191,1) 64%,rgba(178,178,178,1) 100%);
    background: url(../img/bg.png), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  rgba(84,84,84,1) 0%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 34%,rgba(191,191,191,1) 64%,rgba(178,178,178,1) 100%);
    background: url(../img/bg.png), linear-gradient(135deg,  rgba(84,84,84,1) 0%,rgba(117,117,117,1) 34%,rgba(191,191,191,1) 64%,rgba(178,178,178,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#545454', endColorstr='#b2b2b2',GradientType=1 );
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

This should be correct, since it has been made with: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

So there is the whole background working in each browser, the image and the gradient are shown, and even in Opera it works actually, but the background is missing at the bottom, only in the footer. The background is white there and Firebug/Dragonfly won't let me focus on that, although it is still within the body and my '#website' tag.

```
<div id="footer">
        <ul id="footermenu">
            <li class="section"><a onclick="lightbox_open();"><img src="img/socialmedia/sitenotice.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="section"><a href="#" target="_new"><img src="img/socialmedia/itunes.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="section"><a href="#" target="_new"><img src="img/socialmedia/soundcloud.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="section"><a href="#" target="_new"><img src="img/socialmedia/youtube.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="section"><a href="#" target="_new"><img src="img/socialmedia/twitter.png" /></a></li>
            <li class="section"><a href="#" target="_new"><img src="img/socialmedia/facebook.png" /></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

#footer{
    width: 960px;
    margin: -10px auto 0;
    text-align: right;
}

#footermenu li{
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 5px 10px 5px;
}
```

I finally tried to do a workaround as the following snippet shows, like giving opera specifically the background color, which is firstly not really correct, because of the gradient, and secondary it does not work as well.

JS

```
if (window.opera){
    document.getElementById('html').style.backgroundColor = '#b2b2b2';
    document.getElementById('html').style.marginTop = '-10px';
}
```

CSS

```
html{
    background-color:inherit;
    margin-top:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? [I made one](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gQSKv/) from your sources, but it doesn't really show anything.

Comment: Hmm I never did this before but I will try to. Or do you just mean a screenshot so you can see my issue?